# Perl matching and transform

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching, match, transform

In perl the matching not works but the transform works in LWP

for eg

```
if($aa =~ m/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/)
```

This is not working

but

```
if($aa =~ s/.*?about//s)
```

This works for LWP what was the exact problem

*From comment:*

Input data is a html web source page inbetween the page it will contain for eg

```
<html><div><span>23344<\/span><\/div><\/html>
```

now i have to match `23344` with `$aa=~ m/<span>(.*?)<\/span>` 
but this is not working instead transform works

```
$aa =~ s/(<html>.*?<span>)\d+(<\/span>.*?<\/html>)/$1/$2/
```

This transform that works #Robin

Comment: What's your input data, what's the desired output? what does 'not working' exactly mean?

Comment: `s/.*?about/s` is not valid Perl

Comment: I'm getting `Substitution replacement not terminated` for your "working" example.

Comment: Input data is a html web source page inbetween the page it will contain for eg <html><div><span>23344<\/span><\/div><\/html> now i have to match 23344 with $aa=~ m/<span>(.*?)<\/span> but this is not working instead transform works $aa =~ s/(<html>.*?<span>)\d+(<\/span>.*?<\/html>)/$1/$2/ This trnasform that works #Robin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $aa = '<html><div><span>23344</span></div></html>';

if ($aa =~ m/<span>(.+)<\/span>/) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi the problem is i dont have any html content to store in $aa varaible i use curl to retrive data. the problem for me is the matching prints the complete source file and transform prints only the requried data

Comment: @user3231692 If you insist on using a regex for this, make sure you use non-greedy matching: `.*?`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions for parsing html.  There are too many edges cases to be able to handle it effectively or efficiently.

Instead use an actual html parser like [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3a%3aDOM):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Mojo::DOM;

my $aa = '<html><div><span>23344</span></div></html>';

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($aa);
print $dom->find('html > div > span')->text;
```

Comment: Love this will try from next step :)

Comment: The following webcast does a good job of teaching what it's capable of in about 8 minutes: http://mojocasts.com/e5

Comment: Wow amazing tutorial u helped me a lot thanks @Miller